# Python doesn't recognize standard library modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

I can't import standard library modules (like ssl and tkinter) when I'm **not** running Python from "/Python3.8.10/Modules" directory:

```
/Python3.8.10/Modules/# python
>>> import ssl
Traceback(most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl            # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ssl'
```

Same error happens if I try to import "_ssl" directly.
When I'm running Python in /Python3.8.10/Modules" directory everything works fine.
What could be causing this error?

I am using Debian and I used this tutorial https://linuxhint.com/install-python-debian-10/ to install it.

Comment: Is `/Python3.8.10/Modules` the full directory path? No `/usr/something`? If so, that's an unusual path to see.

Comment: Yes. When I installed python I just unzipped it in "/".

Comment: `import sys print(sys.path)` mine gives `['', 'C:\\p\\python38.zip', 'C:\\p\\DLLs', 'C:\\p\\lib', 'C:\\p', 'C:\\p\\lib\\site-packages']`. what about yours?

Comment: I'm not sure what OS you're on, exactly what you unzipped, or what steps you took after that, but it looks like you've got your Python kind of scrambled with the Python 3.8 that comes with your system. (Also, Python 3.8 comes with your system. You didn't need to install it.)

Comment: I am on Debian. I unzipped (untar-ed) Python-3.8.10.tgz (Which comes from the Python website).

Comment: sys.path gives me: ['', '/usr/local/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages']

Comment: Generally you need to *install* Python on whatever OS you are using. The installer will give you a choice of where to install it.

Comment: @Michlol502 can you try find the ssl library in `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages`? i'm wondering `/Python3.8.10/Modules` is not a valid python installation since all `sys.path` point to `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/`. suggest remove `/Python3.8.10/`

Comment: @LeiYang I tried to remove `/Python3.8.10/`. Still the same error occurs

Comment: @martineau I used this [tutorial](https://linuxhint.com/install-python-debian-10) to install it. It doesn't seem to give a choice of installation path.

Comment: When you install it from source as shown in the tutorial, you're effectively choosing the installation directory path which is where the `make -j 2` build command will be executed (`~:Python-3.9.1`). That location was determined by the earlier `wget` command that downloaded the `Python-3.9.1.tgz` souce code tar file.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your comment you didn't install Python, but just downloaded and unzipped the Source Code.

> I am on Debian. I unzipped (untar-ed) Python-3.8.10.tgz (Which comes from the Python website).

If you download the tar ball directly you still have to build Python by `cd`-ing into the Location you extracted it to and then running:

```sh
$ ./configure --enable-optimizations
$ make -j 4
$ sudo make altinstall  # altinstall will install Python3.8 at /usr/bin/Python3.8 instead of /usr/bin/Python which could overwrite previously installed versions.
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.8 # ONLY if you want Python3.8 to be available as just python
```

Edit: Those are just the commands that i remembered out of my head which worked for me on various systems. They also have some requirements (`build-essentials` and `make` being two of them) so this might not work for you.

See [here](https://www.build-python-from-source.com/) or probably on any site when searching for *build Python from source* in your favorite search engine.